# How can I reset and manually uninstall touchpad-indicator gnome extension?

Tags: gnome, touchpad, indicator, extension

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 20.04, Gnome shell 3.36.8, that has the touchpad-indicator by askmrsinh gnome extension. It worked great initially but perhaps with some recent update, has an error. I can no longer turn it off or change it's settings. The problem is that it does not enable my touchpad when the mouse is unplugged. I want to be able to use the touchpad again and manually uninstall touchpad-indicator, but I cannot seem to.

I've tried killing the touchpad-indicator process, and deleting the touchpad-indicator@orangeshirt folder under /home/username/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions. I've tried updating or uninstalling from the GNOME Shell Extension Website addon. It only shows a red "error" button. The extension is not listed under Tweaks, Extensions. I've tried running `touchpad-indicator -c` from the command line which returns "Another instance of Touchpad-Indicator is working," even after I've killed the process. I've tried installing an older version. I've tried editing the touchpad-indicator.conf file manually under /home/username/.config/touchpad-indicator. I've tried manually installing it from the command line as per https://github.com/askmrsinh/touchpad-indicator but the git clone line fails when asking for authentication, "Support for password authentication was removed..."

When I try to go to touchpad-indicator settings, the window says, "Somethings gone wrong," with these technical details:
The settings of extension touchpad-indicator@orangeshirt had an error:

```
TypeError: this.pointingDevices.filter is not a function
```

Stack trace:

```
_filterByType@/home/username/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/touchpad-indicator@orangeshirt/xinput.js:171:64
_populateDebugTab@/home/username/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/touchpad-indicator@orangeshirt/prefs.js:181:32
TouchpadIndicatorSettings@/home/username/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/touchpad-indicator@orangeshirt/prefs.js:61:14
buildPrefsWidget@/home/username/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/touchpad-indicator@orangeshirt/prefs.js:242:20
_init@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/extensionsService.js:207:40
OpenExtensionPrefsAsync/<@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/extensionsService.js:122:28
asyncCallback@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:132:13
run@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/dbusService.js:175:20
main@resource:///org/gnome/Shell/Extensions/js/main.js:19:13
run@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/script/package.js:222:19
start@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/script/package.js:206:5
@/usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.Shell.Extensions:1:17
```

Can anyone help me enable my touchpad and uninstall touchpad-indicator, or get it working again? I'm at my limit and don't know what else to do.

Comment: Update: I finally got touchpad-indicator working. But the problem runs deeper. Kernel 5.15 is not detecting the ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad when I check `xinput list`. What do I need to do to get the touchpad recognized? (When I boot from my old 20.04 installation USB Kernel 5.08, the touchpad works just fine.)

Comment: I forgot to say how I got the touchpad-indicator working. The problem was that I had installed touchpad-indicator two different ways, one the orangeshirt extension and the other the artreao apt. I uninstalled and reinstalled the apt, then I was able to delete the extension.